# How to remove all old files in directory using node js

Tags: node.js, file, directory

I have directory with files.

I would like to delete (zip) files which were created before 7days ago.

I would like to run this script every day.

I can get all files in dir using:

```
  fs.readdirSync('/data/mongodump/').forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
```

But I dont know how to compare (get) dates, then I can call `unlink`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can you `FS.statsSync()` native API where `ctime` is the last changed time, but you can also use `birthtime` for creation date.

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback

```js
fs.readdirSync('/data/mongodump/').forEach(file => {
  const isOlder = fs.statSync(`/data/mongodump/${file}`).ctime < Date.now() - 604800000 // 604800000 = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

  if (isOlder) {
    fs.unlinkSync(`/data/mongodump/${file}`)
  } 

})
```

Bests,